# C# get dictionary value from TracePoints while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, dictionary

What is the proper syntax to obtain a dictionary key value pair when using trace points?

With a property like the following

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> SomeDictionary { get; set; }
```

I am trying to set a break point with actions on the setter method to trace all incoming values. I've tried the following but none of them work.

```
{value}        'this gives me a count of how many items are in the dictionary

{value.Value}  'throws an exception, 'Value' doesn't exist

{value[Value]} 'the name 'Value' does not exist in the current context
```

[image]

Comment: what????????????????????????

Comment: Did you mean to tag something else like javascript? This is (obviously) not c# syntax, not only would it not return anything it would never even compile.

Comment: Are you referring to [TracePoints](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/10/tracepoints/) in the debugger?

Comment: yes this is referring to TracePoints while debugging. apologies for confusion, added more tags and picture

Comment: is value a dictionary or KVP?

Comment: @Aaron I updated the question to hopefully clarify it a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `SomeDictionary`:

```
        public class Example
        {
            public Dictionary<string, decimal> SomeDictionary { get; set; }

            public Example()
            {
                SomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
                string key = "key";
                SomeDictionary[key] = 10.0M;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var example = new Example();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

If we put a tracepoint at the end of the constructor after the dictionary is defined and the key is added - Tracepoint action:

```
SomeDictionary: {SomeDictionary}; SomeDictionary[key]: {SomeDictionary[key]}
```

We can inspect the dictionary - Output:

```
SomeDictionary: Count = 1; SomeDictionary[key]: 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the dictionary by using

```
{ map["key1"] }
```

or using variable to access the keyvalue pair.

[image]